# How to properly get standard default Android state drawables

Tags: android

I normally don't override styles in my apps because I want to remain as pure Android as possible, but I need to have a list of Views that behaves like a ListView, but can't be put in a ListView for various reasons.

So I'm trying to set the state drawable of this View using `android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"` but this gives me an orange color, instead of the standard gray or blue (or maybe orange is the standard color and all the devices I've used override that?).  Any ideas on how to accomplish what I want?

Edit: To clarify, I don't want to set it to be either blue or gray or orange, I want it to vary based on  what device user is running on.  And if some OEM has decided to override the default value, then I want it to use that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `list_selector_holo_dark` or `list_selector_holo_light` to give it a holo look.

Comment: I'm trying that but it gives an error "Resource is not public".  I'm compiling against API 19, maybe it used to be public?

Comment: How about android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" ?

Comment: Thanks, `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` worked.